# Tensorflow code not using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have a Nvidia GTX 1080 running on an Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to implement a convolutional autoencoder using tensorflow 1.0.1 but the program doesn't seem to use the GPU at all. I verified this using `watch nvidia-smi` and `htop`. The output after running the program is as follows:

```
  1 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
  2 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
  3 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
  4 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
  5 I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
  6 Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
  7 Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
  8 Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
  9 Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
 10 getting into solving the reconstruction loss
 11 Dimension of z i.e. our latent vector is [None, 100]
 12 Dimension of the output of the decoder is [100, 28, 28, 1]
 13 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available     on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 14 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are availab    le on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 15 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are availab    le on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 16 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available     on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 17 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available     on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 18 W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available     on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
 19 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
 20 name: GeForce GTX 1080
 21 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
 22 pciBusID 0000:0a:00.0
 23 Total memory: 7.92GiB
 24 Free memory: 7.81GiB
 25 W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x34bccc0
 26 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties: 
 27 name: GeForce GTX 1080
 28 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
 29 pciBusID 0000:09:00.0
 30 Total memory: 7.92GiB
 31 Free memory: 7.81GiB
 32 W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x34c0940
 33 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 2 with properties:
 34 name: GeForce GTX 1080
 35 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
 36 pciBusID 0000:06:00.0
 37 Total memory: 7.92GiB
 38 Free memory: 7.81GiB
 39 W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x34c45c0
 40 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 3 with properties:
 41 name: GeForce GTX 1080
 42 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
 43 pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
 44 Total memory: 7.92GiB
 45 Free memory: 7.81GiB
 46 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 2 3
 47 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y Y Y Y
 48 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   Y Y Y Y
 49 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 2:   Y Y Y Y
 50 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 3:   Y Y Y Y
 51 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus i    d: 0000:0a:00.0)
 52 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus i    d: 0000:09:00.0)
 53 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus i    d: 0000:06:00.0)
 54 I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:3) -> (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus i    d: 0000:05:00.0)
```

Can there be a problem in my code, I have also tried specifying it to use a particular device using `with tf.device("/gpu:0"):` before building the graph. Do let me know if any further information is required.

**Edit 1** Output of nvidia-smi

```
exx@ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Apr 19 20:50:07 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.48                 Driver Version: 367.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:05:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 38%   54C    P8    12W / 180W |   7715MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:06:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 38%   55C    P8     8W / 180W |   7715MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:09:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   50C    P8     8W / 180W |   7715MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:0A:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 35%   54C    P2    41W / 180W |   7833MiB /  8113MiB |      8%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     24228    C   python3                                       7713MiB |
|    1     24228    C   python3                                       7713MiB |
|    2     24228    C   python3                                       7713MiB |
|    3     24228    C   python3                                       7831MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

htop shows that it uses around 100% of one of the CPU cores. My basis for saying that it's not using gpu is because of the GPU usage %. It showed 8%  on this one but it usually is at 0%.

Comment: It looks like it's finding 4 GPUs just fine, I don't see anything abnormal in that output. You shouldn't need to specify `tf.device("/gpu:0")`. Are all your CPUs being used during training? Can you paste the output of nvidia-smi? Do you see python processes in the output of nividia-smi, or just that GPU usage seems to be 0%?

Comment: @DavidParks I have added the output of nvidia-smi and the python processes are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're running on the GPU, everything is configured correctly from that perspective, but it looks like speed is really bad. Make sure you run nvidia-smi a number of times to get a sense of how it's doing, it might show 100% one moment and 8% another.

It's normal to get about ~80% utilization rates from the GPU because there's time lost in loading each batch from the core memory to the GPU before each run (there are new features coming out shortly to improve that, GPU queues in TF).

If you're getting lower performance than ~80% from your GPU you're doing things wrong. There are 2 likely and common causes that come to mind:

1) You're doing a bunch of pre-processing between steps, so the GPU runs quick, but then you're blocked on a single CPU thread doing a bunch of non tensorflow work. Move this to its own thread, load data to the GPU from a python `Queue`

2) Large chunks of data are being moved back and forth between the CPU and GPU memory. The bandwidth between the CPU and GPU can be a bottleneck if you doing this.

Try adding some timers between the start of a training/inference batch and the end and see if you're spending a lot of time outside of tensorflow operations.

Comment: Thanks your advise worked. It's usage is consistently around 90%. I need advice on one more thing. Currently it's using only one of the cores of the GPU and the rest of them are at 0%. How can I fix that.

Comment: There's a discussion of using multiple gpu's here, there's also a link at the bottom to an example implementation: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Comment: @saharudra, you can find an example for multiple GPU implementation in the following link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py